# a Breakpoint on a Class Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, breakpoints

I am trying to set a Breakpoint on a Class c++. As explained [**here**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/habibh/2009/09/10/class-breakpoint-how-to-set-a-breakpoint-on-a-c-class-in-the-visual-studio-debugger/), I have to set a breakpoint such as *MyClass*::* in order to insert a break to all methods inside *MyClass*.

However, when I do local window debugging in visual studio (v.2013), there is a exclamation mark on the breakpoint saying that the breakpoint will not currently be hit, The function cannot be found.

Any idea would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You cannot break on a type. You need specific functions or data which have memory addresses.

Comment: Actually CustomAllocator is a class. It is not a type.

Comment: I fail to see the difference. It's not a object, nor a function, so it's a type. So is `CustomAllocator::*`. Its a "pointer to member of `CustomAllocator`". Everything in quotes in the previous sentence sums up to a typename.

Comment: please see: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/habibh/2009/09/10/class-breakpoint-how-to-set-a-breakpoint-on-a-c-class-in-the-visual-studio-debugger/

Comment: Ah, I did not know about this. I wouldn't be surprised all versions beyond VS2008 do not have this feature though...